# pyparsing: how to parse nested function which start with particular function name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I want to use pyparsing to parse a nested function which start with particular function name.

Just like this:

```
tag("tag_name_1", value_equal("proxy.province", "value", "return_value", test(1,2)))
```

The string waited to be parsed starts with the function named 'tag'.

The problem is that why *exprStack* doesn't contain "tag" function?

```
import pyparsing as pp
from typing import Any, List, Dict


def debug(*args, **kwargs):
    print("debug"+"---"*10)
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    print("debug"+"---"*10)
    # return "debug"
    return "debug"

def insert_fn_argcount_tuple(t):
    fn = t.pop(0)
    num_args = len(t)
    print((fn, num_args))
    t.insert(0, (fn, num_args))



def push_first(toks):
    exprStack.append(toks[0])


def to_string(toks):
    pass

LPAREN, RPAREN, COMMA = map(pp.Suppress, '(),') 
ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums+"_")
integer = pp.Word(pp.nums)
string = (pp.QuotedString("'") | pp.QuotedString('"')).setParseAction()
expr = pp.Forward()
expr_list = pp.delimitedList(pp.Group(expr))
tag_fn = ("tag" + LPAREN + expr_list + RPAREN).setParseAction(insert_fn_argcount_tuple)
fn_call = (ident + LPAREN + expr_list + RPAREN).setParseAction(insert_fn_argcount_tuple)
atom = ( (fn_call | string | integer) | pp.Group(LPAREN+expr+RPAREN)).addParseAction(push_first)
# atom = ( fn_call | pp.Group(LPAREN+expr+RPAREN)).addParseAction(push_first)
expr <<= atom 

bnf = pp.Forward()
bnf <<= tag_fn

funcs = """tag
value_equal
value_contain
value_match
value
"""


# functions
def tag(tag_name: str, value:Any)->Dict:
    if not tag_name or not value:
        return {}
    return {"tag_name": tag_name, "tag_value": value}

def test(*args, **kwargs):
    return ""

def value_equal(key: str, value, default=None, test=None):
    print(f"---{value_equal}---")
    print(f"key: {key}, value: {value}, defaul: {default}, test:{test}")
    return "value-1"

fns = {
    "tag": tag,
    "value_equal": value_equal,
    "test": test
}
exprStack = []

def evaluate_stack(s:List): # List param will be changed after invoke evaluate_stack function
    fn, arg_nums = s.pop(), 0
    if isinstance(fn, tuple):
        fn, arg_nums = fn
    if fn in fns:
        args = reversed([evaluate_stack(s) for _ in range(arg_nums)])
        return fns[fn](*args)
    else:
        return fn

test_str = """tag("tag_name_1", value_equal("proxy.province", "value", "return_value", test(1,2)))"""
# test_str = "123"
p = bnf.parse_string(test_str)
print(f"\nexprStack:{exprStack}\n")
t = evaluate_stack(exprStack)
print(f"tag:{t}")
```

The output of above code is:

```
('test', 2)
('value_equal', 4)
('tag', 2)

exprStack:['tag_name_1', 'proxy.province', 'value', 'return_value', '1', '2', ('test', 2), ('value_equal', 4)\]
```

I expect that *exprStack* contains tag function. maybe like this:

```
exprStack:['tag_name_1', 'proxy.province', 'value', 'return_value', '1', '2', ('test', 2), ('value_equal', 4), ('tag', 2)\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really pretty close. The thing is, the push_first parse action is attached to atoms, but tag_fn is not an atom. So it won't get its data pushed to expr_stack.

To fix this:

1. Change atom to include tag_fn, something like this:

   ```
   atom = ((tag_fn | fn_call | string | integer) | pp.Group(LPAREN+expr+RPAREN)).addParseAction(push_first)
   ```
2. Change bnf to expr instead of tag_fn:

   ```
   bnf <<= expr
   ```

With these two changes, I get this for expr_stack:

```
exprStack:['tag_name_1', 'proxy.province', 'value', 'return_value', '1', '2', ('test', 2), ('value_equal', 4), ('tag', 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this way, but it couldn't limit the text string which is waited to parse start with 'tag' function

Comment: I'm not following your comment. Please edit your question to include the new input string and the desired result.